# Как менять UIStatusBarStyle Light на Default по необходимости?

Tags: objective-c

В ViewController.m есть две функции:

```
- (void)style_light{
}

- (void)style_default{
}
```

Что вставить в эти функции, чтобы при их вызове менять UIStatusBarStyleLightContent на UIStatusBarStyleDefault и обратно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подставьте:

```
- (void)style_light{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)style_default{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
//и почему snake_case?
```

И в `Info.plist` укажите

`View controller-based status bar appearance`  `NO`

Raw:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>

подскажите куда это вставить?

Comment: В AppDelegate.m какой-то код нужно вставить?

Comment: @NazarVozniy raw - это если смотреть Info.plist в исходном виде (Open as -> Source Code). В AppDelegate.m укажите какой изначально должен быть statusBarStyle